# is it correct to give binding to two variables

Tags: sparql

normally I do the binding like this: (maybe the correct name is not binding but you get me)

```
values ?x {bo:ania}
```

but now I have to bind two variables, so I do this:

```
values (?defaultUserMatched ?defaultUserNotMatched) {(1 0.5)}
```

but it **sounds** like the value of `defaultUserNotMatched` is 1, not 0.5,

to be honest, I am not 100% sure, that is why I am asking you if the way to bind two values like I did is correct

Comment: i found the error, the way i am doing it is correct, the error was in another place

Comment: Note that `values (?x ?y) {(1 2)(3 4)}` is very different from `values ?x {1 3} values ?y {2 4}`. As long as you understand the difference,  it's fine to bind multiple variables with a single **values**.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor `values (?x ?y) {(1 2)(3 4)}` means the pair ?x ?y is bind once to `1 2` respectively and then to `3 4` respectively, so when ?x is 1, ?y is 2, and when ?x is 3, ?y is 4, right? `values ?x {1 3}` means ?x has two values, `values ?y {2 4}` ?y has two values, but it could happen that ?x is `1` while ?y is `4` , this wouldn't happen in the first case, right please ?

Comment: That's right.  As long as you're using the right one for your use case, you're all set.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor thank you, please write an answer here, moreover, i got another questions now, could you have a lock please?